# Qt 5.2.1 add wwWidgets to a project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qtgui, wwwidgets

I am trying to use [wwWidgets](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/) under windows with Qt, but I am having some trouble compiling projects with widgets from wwWiget...

The installer run successfully I am using the: standard Qt SDK installations installer. But whenever I try to add `QT += wwwidgets` to the project file QT gives me the error:

`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: wwwidgets`

Does anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Qt 5

Apparently, they do not have proper Qt 5 examples, nor is their buildsystem quite ready for this `QT += wwwidgets` thing. I think the best would be if you could contribute back to the project by establishing it. It should not be that hard and someone may eventually do that if you do not do it. One example to look at would be QtSerialPort how to implement it properly.

For the time being, if you do not want to help with this, you could always use `LIBS` and `INCLUDEPATH` to work it around, but you may need to drop that when it gets properly implemented in the module.

### Qt 4

[As their examples show](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/doc/html/colorpickers-colorpickers-pro.html), you will need to use the following in your qmake project file:

```
CONFIG += wwwidgets
```

For further details, check [their usage](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/#usage) on the main page, as well:

> Usage
>
> Usage of wwWidgets in your projects is trivial. Once you install the package on your system all you have to do is to add the following line to your project (.pro) file: CONFIG+=wwwidgets Just remember to run qmake afterwards. From now on you can use wwWidgets includes and classes in your project.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QwwRichTextButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QwwRichTextButton b;
  b.setText("<B>Hello</B> <font color='red'>world</font>");
  b.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

> When distributing the project, remember to deploy the widget library with it along regular Qt libs.

Comment: CONFIG += wwwidgets is deprecated in Qt5.2.1... they say to use QT += instead. So this wil not work

Comment: @Faas: that is not how their examples are written. I am not sure where you have read that CONFIG += wwwidgets is deprecated for their project. They write the opposite on their official website. I do not think you can easily use this library with Qt 5. I did not notice Qt 5 as it was not tagged so. Which OS are you using, btw?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. It is now with the folowing parameters: `LIBS += "C:/wwwidgets/path/lib/libwwwidgets4d.a"` and `INCLUDEPATH += "C:/wwwidgets/path/include/wwWidgets"` (for Windows)

Comment: @Faas: great, what was your solution, manually specifying the path and library name?

Answer (score 3):

if you add manually library it doesnt work either?

like this

```
LIBS += -L"C:\wwwidgets\path\lib" -lwwwidgets.lib
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\wwwidgets\path\include"
```

try that